# Access Parent component from Child component. Use service? What about @ContentChildren?

Tags: angular, angular6, angular7, angular-components

I created an Angular 7 accordion component [SlackBlitz Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/m-angular-accordion):

```
export class AccordionComponent {

  @ContentChildren(PanelComponent) panels: QueryList<PanelComponent>;

  ngAfterContentInit() {
    this.panels.forEach((panel) => {panel.active = false;});
  }

}
```

The PanelComponent is the following:

```
export class PanelComponent {

  @Input() active: boolean;
  @Input() title: string;

  toggle() {
    this.active = !this.active;
  }

}
```

The accordion is working but I need to close all panels when a new one is opened.

I think this could be done in two ways:

1. In PanelComponent being able to access a method on AccordionComponent.
   That method would set one panel active and the rest inactive.

   I don't know how to access Parent Component (Accordion) from Child Component (Panel)
2. Use a AccordionService that would contain the Panels:

   ```
   panels: PanelComponent[] = [];
   ```

   Then inject this service in Accordion and Panel.

   This seems logic but then I stoped using @ContentChildren(PanelComponent).

   In some sense this breaks the relation between Accordion and Panel.

Which solution should I use? Or another?

Am I missing something on my 2 solutions (I don't know how to implement solution 1).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding point 1, you can inject parent component, like the following:

```
constructor(
  @Inject(forwardRef(() => AccordionComponent)) private accordion: AccordionComponent, 
  ...)
```

Using a service also works, but it seems a bit more work for this simple case, IMHO.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily use Event Emitters to solve your purpose.

[See this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/m-angular-accordion-2hjxmg)

Changes done to your code:

**panel.component.ts**

```
 @Input() activate: string;
  @Input() title: string;
  @Output() closeOtherPanels: EventEmitter<string> = new EventEmitter();

  active : boolean = false;

ngOnChanges(changes : SimpleChanges){
  if(changes.activate){
    this.active = this.activate == this.title;
  }
}

  toggle() {
    this.active = !this.active;
    if(this.active){
      this.closeOtherPanels.emit(this.title);
    }
  }
```

**app.component.ts**

```
export class AppComponent  {
  activeTitle : string="";
  name = 'Angular';

  closeOtherPanels(value){
    this.activeTitle=value;
  }
}
```

**app.component.html**

`<accordion>
     <panel title="Panel 1 title" [activate]="activeTitle" 
    (closeOtherPanels)="closeOtherPanels($event)">Panel 1 content</panel>
     <panel title="Panel 2 title" [activate]="activeTitle" (closeOtherPanels)="closeOtherPanels($event)">Panel 2 content</panel>
     <panel title="Panel 3 title" [activate]="activeTitle" (closeOtherPanels)="closeOtherPanels($event)">Panel 3 content</panel>
     <panel title="Panel 4 title" [activate]="activeTitle" (closeOtherPanels)="closeOtherPanels($event)">Panel 4 content</panel>
   </accordion>`